# collection view row colors change on scroll

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have this collection view and i've set the color of it's rows when drawing each row based on it's index. It shows correct color for each row until you scroll down and then go up again. For example if it was in order of R,G,B,R,G,B when scrolling a little bit up and down it might be G,G,R,B,R,B. I have tried setting rasterize layer to both true and false but no luck there too. I don't get why this happens and how to fix it. Because i set the color on cellForItemAt function and it should get called whenever drawing a row again and basing the row color on a list of colors and id of that row it should draw same thing always.

Here is a part of my code.

```
class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
//MARK: Properties

var list = [Item]()
var colors = [[String]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.refreshList(self)
    colors.append(["#ff3e99","#ffa35a"])
    colors.append(["#668dff","#ff53ff"])
    colors.append(["#6ae0d7","#00d3ad"])
}    

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return list.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "xxxx"

    guard let cell = self.collectionView?.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? xxxxCell  else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of xxxx.")
    }
    // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
    let item = list[indexPath.row]
    style(cell: cell.rootView, index: item.id!)

    return cell
}

func style(cell:LGButton, index: Int) {
    cell.gradientStartColor = UIColor(hexString: colors[index % colors.count][0])
    cell.gradientEndColor = UIColor(hexString: colors[index % colors.count][1])
    cell.shadowColor = UIColor(hexString: colors[index % colors.count][0])
    cell.shadowRadius = 8
    cell.shadowOpacity = 0.8
}
```

}

Comment: And where do you apply exactly the gradient? because you just set colors to some vars, but I don't see any CAGradientLayer code.

Comment: I'm using a library that has that part of code underneath. the main drawing works fine only problem is with scrolling and color change.

Answer (score 0):

Issues when scrolling makes me think it's a cell reuse problem. Try implementing `prepareForReuse` inside your custom xxxxCell `UICollectionViewCell`. Reset the properties and see if that helps.

Something like:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    gradientStartColor = UIColor.clear
    gradientEndColor = UIColor.clear
    shadowColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Comment: Thanks but neither of those three values can accept nil value

Comment: @minimlistic - try setting them to be clear then. The idea is that the cell is being reused but the values aren't being reset - thus your issue.

Comment: @JaredH Although that little bit of code can still be translated easily, it is still best to write the code underneath, in the language they did and what the tag says (`swift`).

Comment: @JaredH No, still produces messy colors for background and shadow on scroll

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used LGButton, but looking at https://github.com/loregr/LGButton/blob/develop/LGButton/Classes/LGButton.swift, assuming that is the code you are using, once the gradient has been set, you cannot change it. So when your cells get reused, even though you're attempting to reset the gradient colors in your `style` function, the LGButton code is not honoring the change.

In the above link, on line 398 (as of this writing), the first line of the function `setupGradientBackground` checks to see if variable `gradient` is nil, if so it sets `gradient` which means it will not change later when you update the gradient start and end colors. I think that is a flaw in LGButton -- when you change the value of the start or end colors, it should recalculate the gradient.

It looks to me like you may be able to set gradient to nil to force a recalculation. You probably need to set all the values to nil so the gradient doesn't get reset before you have finished setting all your values.

In the snippet below, I also rename the cell parameter to `button` so the call to it is not misleading -- looking like you are passing a cell rather than a button.

```
func style(button:LGButton, index: Int) {
    button.gradientStartColor = nil
    button.gradientEndColor = nil
    button.gradient?.removeFromSuperLayer()
    button.gradient = nil
    button.gradientStartColor = UIColor(hexString: colors[index % colors.count][0])
    button.gradientEndColor = UIColor(hexString: colors[index % colors.count][1])
    button.shadowColor = UIColor(hexString: colors[index % colors.count][0])
    button.shadowRadius = 8
    button.shadowOpacity = 0.8
}
```

Comment: In a comment to another answer, you indicated that you cannot set the values to nil. In the LGButton code linked to above, the `gradientStartColor`, `gradientEndColor`, and `gradient` are all optional, so you should be able to set them to nil. But maybe you using some other LGButton implementation.

Comment: You may also need to call `button.gradient?.removeFromSuperLayer()` before setting gradient to nil.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. however gradient object seems to be marked as internal and not accessible from code and setting the gradientStartColor to nil didn't helped. You were right it was optional i don't know why it was throwing error before but now even with setting those to null the result was same with messy color choices. I agree with you that seems to be LGButton problem too.